# Execute a command from another group

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, groups

In Linux, I have the following `id`:

```
uid=1005(username) gid=1005(username) groups=1005(username),33(www-data),1002(git)
```

I'd like to change my effective gid to `git` so that everything I create will belong to `gid` group. E.g. `touch testfile` gives `owner=username group=git`

How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change your current group using the **newgrp**  commmand:

```
~$ id
uid=1000(bas) gid=1000(bas) groups=1000(bas),24(cdrom)
~$ newgrp - cdrom
~$ id
uid=1000(bas) gid=24(cdrom) groups=1000(bas),24(cdrom)
~$ touch foo && ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 bas cdrom 0 Jul 24 13:58 foo
```

Groups can be locked or have a password. See the manpage for more details.

```
man newgrp
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have suitable sudo permissions you can run a shell as the new group

```
username    ALL=(:git) /bin/bash
```

this allows username to run `/bin/bash` as `username:git`

```
id
uid=1005(test) gid=1005(test) groups=1005(test)

touch testfile
ls -l testfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 test test 0 Jul 24 11:19 testfile

sudo -g git /bin/bash
id
uid=1005(test) gid=1003(git) groups=1005(test)
rm testfile
touch testfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 test git 0 Jul 24 11:21 testfile
```

You could even use exec to replace your current shell with the one running as the git group

```
exec sudo -g git /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Globally, you cannot - not without changing the user's primary group.

But on a per-directory basis, this is trivially achieved by setting the setgid bit on the directory, and `chown`ing said directory to the correct group.

Anything created below said directory will inherit the gid, regardless of the user who created it.